# Should I use App Maker's Server Script, Calculated Client, or Relations to filter data for display

Tags: google-app-maker

I think I'm missing a core concept in how to filter and display App Maker data.

### Goal

1) I'd like to maintain two manual-mode data models.

```
Persons:
  PrimaryEmail
  personName
Vehicles:
  PrimaryEmail
  vehicleColor
```

2) I'd like to display two tables **side by side** on the same page.

Showing *all the vehicles* in one table and *only the user's vehicles* in the second table. *PrimaryEmail* is the key they share.

---

### What I've Tried

**Server Script**

This query script for a third datasource, `UserVehicles`, returns the records I want to display in the second table.

```
function getUserVehicleData() {
  var uE = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var q = app.models.Vehicle.newQuery();
  q.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = uE;
  var d = q.run();
  return d;
}
```

But, I found it necessary for the client to frequently call `app.datasources.UserVehicle.load();` but even still the second table would not show the updated/added record from (table one uses the `Vehicle` datasource, table two is using `UserVehicles`). I *think* I need to also work inside the load() callback, but I do not see how to tell the second table there is refreshed data in `UserVehicles`.

**Client Calculated**

This option *sounds* right. I'd like the client to query the server for the records where the Vehicle's `PrimaryEmail` matches the current user.

I do not see how records from the server are filtered on the client. Unlike the server script API, `var data = app.models.Vehicle.newQuery();` is not valid client script. So, one does not *load* data into variables in which to loop/filter/create new records in the client calculated script?

**Relations**

I replicated a tutorial and created a ONE to MANY relations between People and Vehicles. This introduced errors around deprecated foreign keys. Also, I couldn't reason how to use this relation to the filter for the current user. (I'm not 100% grasping the UI).

### Question

I want to understand how to display updated and filtered data and how that data should be filtered (server, client calculated, relations). I must be missing something, this must be simple to do.

Comment: Many ways to approach this, but the easiest is have your persons table, if you wish to filter this then apply the filter in the datasource's query script with a query of `query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals() = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` then in your panel where you have the persons table make sure the panel datasource is set to 'persons' and drag a new table into this panel with datasource as `persons: vehicles (relation)`. Also make sure to prefetch vehicles in your persons datasource.

Comment: Where does `query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals() = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` go? The datasource query script must return an array of records. *Prefetch* is a big help, Thanks!

Comment: That filter goes in your datasource query script (server) for persons, but only if you need persons filtered based on the current user. If you need all/several persons returned then don’t apply the filter.

Comment: Markus, sounds like you understand App Maker well. Your comments are mixing server scripts and relations. And the server script you provide is an expression not an assignment that returns errors. In my question I'd like two tables of vehicles, not people. I'll bet you know how to do this, but your comments don't quite bring it together. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh wow. my thinking around how to use relations was way off. I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I suppose if you want two tables, one showing all vehicles and the other only showing vehicles the current user is assigned to, then you should probably go with two separate datasources in your vehicles model.

Comment: Call one 'AllVehicles' and the other 'UserVehicles' or whatever suits your needs. Have both datasources set to automatically load. On the AllVehicles datasource leave the query builder active and don't enter anything.

Comment: On the UserVehicles datasource change it to query script and enter `query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals() = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` in the case that there is no relation between persons and vehicles, or `query.filters.Persons.PrimaryEmail._equals() = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` in the case that there is a relation between persons and vehicles. Then add `return query.run();` on the second line of your query script.

Comment: Yes! and the final bit is `app.pages.UserVehicles.createChildren();` <--- this is the _client script_ to get updated data to **display** in the widget. This goes _inside_ the `saveChanges` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

I used a server script to solve this.

```
function getUserVehicleData() {
  var uE = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var q = app.models.Vehicle.newQuery();
  q.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = uE;
  var d = q.run();
  return d;
}
```

The piece I was missing was this bit of Client Script.

```
app.pages.UserVehicles.createChildren();
```

Without it, the UI would not refresh the list to use the updated data from the datasource.

Thanks Markus!